# Cannot start Tomcat v7 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

when i run my hello world program, this error appears. How do i debug this one?

Problem Occured:

> 'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>   Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

these are the errors in the console:

> May 23, 2013 7:42:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Program
>   Files\Juno.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml]
>   May 23, 2013 7:42:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Program
>   Files\Juno.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml]
>   May 23, 2013 7:42:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.

Comment: You don't give many details. Edit your question and write exactly what you are developing and what you already achieved and what you are trying to do what causes the error.

Comment: It's a web-app hello world, right? You've defined Tomcat server correctly? It's not already running (for example as a windows service) ?

Comment: when i run a program, the server always failed to start. What should i do?

Comment: How do i define Tomcat server?

Comment: I have reinstalled tomcat server and eclipse still my program doesnt run, this error keeps on blocking me. What should i do to solve this one?

Comment: Is your hello world program a web app or a plain java application. Post the code of your program to allow us to help you out.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with 'tmp0' folder empty. Tried setting the permissions etc but still no good. Then I changed the tomcat configuration -> Changed Server Location from "use workspace location" to "**Use tomcat installation**". Here's how to do that:

- open "Servers"'s view
- double click onto the Tomcat server
- in the "Server Locations" fieldset, select "Use tomcat installation"

Comment: to reformulate the same answer: open "Servers"'s view, double click onto the Tomcat server, into the "Server Locations" fieldset, select "Use tomcat installation"